# Identify unique rows when comparing dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes with the same columns, with potentially intersecting rows:

```
df1    df2


A B    A B

m m    1 2
1 2    3 4
3 4    5 6
5 6    x x
n n    y y
```

I need to identify which rows are in df1 but not in df2 and vice versa. Solution dataframes could look like this:

```
indf1_notindf2

A B
m m
n n

indf2_notindf1

A B
x x
y y
```

Or just one dataframe, like this:

```
A B FLAG
m m only_df1
n n only_df1
x x only_df2
y y only_df2
```

Or any other way of solving it...

I have tried concatenating both dataframes and dropping duplicates but I couldn't know which dataframe the rows came from. Any help is appreciated. Note: Both dataframes' real size are 500k rows aprox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the following,

```
df1['FLAG'] = 'only_df1'
df2['FLAG'] = 'only_df2'

df = df1.append(df2).drop_duplicates(['A','B'], keep=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do using [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html):

```
# df1 not in df2
df1[~df1.isin(df2.to_dict('l')).all(1)]

   A  B
0  m  m
4  n  n

# df2 not in df1
df1[df1.isin(df2.to_dict('l')).all(1)]

   A  B
1  1  2
2  3  4
3  5  6
```

Answer (score 1):

this is [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with `indicator=True` + [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
m = df1.merge(df2,on=[*df1],how='outer',indicator=True).query("_merge!='both'")
print(m)
```

---

```
   A  B      _merge
0  m  m   left_only
4  n  n   left_only
5  x  x  right_only
6  y  y  right_only
```

you can then use a dictionary to remap `left_only` to `df1` and same for `right_only` as per convenience.